# Property about submodules of noetherian modules over noetherian local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, local-rings

$\def\m{\mathfrak{m}}
$I am trying to show the following commutative algebra result:

> **Proposition.** Let $(R,\m)$ be a noetherian local ring, $M$ be a noetherian module and $M_1,M_2\subset M$ be submodules. If for each non-negative integer $k$ we have $M_1\subset M_2+\m^kM$, then $M_1\subset M_2$.

It was stated to me during a several complex variables lecture without proof, labelled as "Krull's lemma." I have no idea how to prove it. I don't know if I should use Nakayama's lemma in some form or if the lecturer meant the [Krull's intersection theorem](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IP). The thing is that "krull lemma" doesn't give any results on google.

Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: Use the intersection theorem.

Comment: @Mohan do you mean the theorem I linked? That is the thing: I don't know how to use it on this case

Comment: Show that the image of $M_1$ in $M/M_2$ is zero using Krull.

Comment: @Mohan Ah, thanks. Do you want to post that as an answer or should I do it?